# is there any intution as to why this multivariate limit does not exist?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{(x^2-y)^2}{x^4+y^2}$ is supposed to not exist, i.e., we get different limiting values along the axis $y=0$ and the parabolic path of approach $y=x^2$. However, my first intuition would've told me that this limit would exists because this is a rational expression, and the degree of the top expression is equal to the degree of the bottom expression (both 4); that is, they both shrink at a similar rate. Thus, I likely would've tried to bound the expression via the squeeze law. Why does this intuition fail? Is there any other "hints" about this function that would've told me that the limit doesn't exist?

Comment: When talking about polynomials near the origin, it's the minimal degree of the monomials involved that controls the rate of day, not the maximal degree. This is the same as with polynomials of one variable (how fast does $x^3+x$ decay near $x=0$?).

Comment: As for intuition: the function acts like two very different functions along the $x$-axis (where it's identically $1$) and along the given parabola (where it's identically $0$). In $2$ (and more) dimensions, there's room for pathological behaviour like this. Ultimately, it's fine to notice that our intuition is wrong (that's a big part of learning); we just have to be willing to update our intuition as we discover more.